# Changing heading of appendix

Tags: appendices, mwcls

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Blabla}
Aaaa
\chapter{Lablab}
Silly equation \ref{eq:silly} in appendix \ref{ap:1}.
\appendix
\chapter{Something more}\label{ap:1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:silly}
2+2=5
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I got:

```
Contents
1. Blabla
2. Lablab
A. Something more
```

I need:

```
Contents
1. Blabla
2. Lablab
Appendix A. Something more
```

How can make every appendix in form: "Appendix A", "Appending B" etc?

**EDIT:**

I need a change at ToC and in the document (header of chapter).

How can I change a name of 'Appendix' if I want to use other word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load the `appendix` package with its `titletoc` option and use the `appendices` environment to enclose your appendices; this will add "Appendix" to the entries in the ToC. To Add "Appendix" to the headings in the document, a redefinition of `\FormatBlockHeading` (the style used by `mwrep.cls` to typeset chapter headings) will be needed. The following example shows these modifications:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Blabla}
Aaaa

\chapter{Lablab}
Silly equation \ref{eq:silly} in appendix \ref{ap:1}.

\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FormatBlockHeading[1]{%
  \leftskip\@titleindent
  #1{\noindent
  \ifHeadingNumbered
    \@chapapp\ \mw@seccntformat\HeadingNumber
  \fi
  \ignorespaces\HeadingText\@@par}
  }
\makeatother
\chapter{Something more}\label{ap:1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:silly}
2+2=5
\end{equation}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

and an image of the first page of the appendix:

[image]

To change the word "Appenidix", if you are not *loading* `babel`, you can say

```
\renewcommand\appendixname{New Name}
```

in the preamble; if you are loading babel, you'll need

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\appendixname{New Name}}
```

Comment: Edited my original question.

Comment: @Ichibann I've updated my answer providing solutions to the new requirements.

Comment: What about getting the same result but with the article class? FormatBlockHeading doesn't exist there.

Comment: Found it in your answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176032/appendix-title-changing-in-article-class). It might be useful to add the general form in your answer, since article is a more common class, or provide the link.

Comment: +1 for ``\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\appendixname{New Name}}``